# Does the Nest thermostat automatically change modes?

Tags: thermostat, nest

I understand from the Nest website that the thermostat has [heating, cooling, and heat/cool modes](https://nest.com/support/article/How-do-I-switch-between-heating-and-cooling#modes-thermostat). I also know that over time Nest [learns your preferences](https://nest.com/support/article/How-does-Auto-Schedule-learn) based on how you adjust the thermostat, and changes set-points based on this learning.

**Does the learning feature ever include changing the mode, or does this always have to be done manually?** Would Nest automatically switch from heating mode in the winter, to heat/cool in the shoulder seasons, then cooling in the summer?

Comment: On my Nest that would be mode “heat / cool”.  In that mode you set a set point for each, see [this](https://imgur.com/a/TN9SwuC) and [this](https://imgur.com/a/E0kUtvO).  Then I have it set to shift to eco mode (a different pair of set points) when neither phone is connected to local WiFi using the feature “wifi assist”.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience with the Gen 2 it will not. That would be a bit heavy-handed and folks would not be happy to have their AC compressor come on with the winter cover still in place, for example.

It may go into Eco, however, if you're away.

[More on that](https://nest.com/ae/support/article/Learn-how-Eco-Temperatures-work-on-the-Nest-Thermostat)